# Should a package always be purged before upgrading?

Tags: debian, upgrade, libreoffice

I am thinking of upgrading Libreoffice 5 to 6 through backports. Do I have to purge LO5 first? Furthermore, is purging absolutely necessary before upgrading packages in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there’s no need to purge the LibreOffice 5 packages before upgrading to LibreOffice 6, at least if you’re using the Debian-provided LibreOffice packages.

Purging involves removing a package along with its configuration. The only reason to do so is if you want to fully uninstall a package; when you’re upgrading a package, you shouldn’t ever need to do so. Even when a package changes names, if it’s incompatible with the previous version it will declare so in its metadata and the package management system will take care of things for you (which will involve removing the old package, not purging it, so that the new one can import the old package if appropriate, and so that you can revert to the old package if necessary).

I can’t make any guarantees concerning packages from third parties, but you shouldn’t need to purge for upgrades either. You might need to purge before switching from Debian-provided packages and third-party alternatives, but I would expect the installation instructions to tell you so.

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely to make any difference for LO, because you're not likely to have edited system-wide configuration files for an office suite.

When there are system-wide config files that you have modified (and are also different in the upgraded package), you may choose to purge them and start afresh rather than handle the ugly conffile questions.  However you can equally answer to overwrite with the new package config when `dpkg` asks you.  Or, you can choose to keep your own.  In either case, the other version will be available, so you can inspect it, change your mind, merge them, whatever. (.dpkg-new / .dpkg-old)

https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/

---

More generally, it is not necessary to purge before performing a supported upgrade path. Is stable -> backports a supported upgrade path? Eh. "`install -t jessie && remove && install -t jessie-backports` will fail, specifically for icinga2-classicui.  Use purge" -- personal log. So yes, at least be prepared for weird issues in some cases.